# derivative of a function with some indicator function as one of its component

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Given a set  $S$ of data points $(x_i,y_i)$ where $x_i \in \mathbf{R}^n y_i\in \{1,...,m\}$ and $m$ vectors $w^j\in \mathbf{R}^n,j=1,...,m$, where $w^j$ is a variable vector.  We need to find the derivative of the function(ridge loss of support vector machine) :

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k^j}\frac{C}{n}\sum_{(x_i,y_i)\in S} \sum_{j'=1}^m max\{0, 1-(\langle w^{j'}, x_i \rangle ) \chi\{y_i=j'\}\}$$

I don't know how to deal with the term $\chi\{y_i=j'\}= 1 \text{ if } y_i=j' \text{ and } -1 \text{ otherwise } $.

**Update:** I have computer the derivative now, it is as follow, I'm wondering if this is right? :

Let's first compute derivative of the loss for a single fixed data point $(x_i,y_i)$. We'll let $w=[w^1,...,w^m]$ be the matrix of weights were each $w^{j'}$ are column vectors.  We'll let $\lambda_1=\chi_{\{y_i=1\}}, \lambda_2=\chi_{\{y_i=2\}}...\lambda_m=\chi_{\{y_i=m\}}$. We'll let $\overline{\textbf{1}} \in \mathbf{R}^m$ be the column vector of all $1's$. We'll let $\overline{\textbf{0}} \in \mathbf{R}^m$ be the vector of all zeros. We'll let $X^T=[x_1^T,...,x_n^T]$ be the matrix of data where each $x_i \in \mathbf{R}^p$ is a column vector. Then the hinge loss for the single data points can be written as $$ \lVert \max_{entriewise} \{ \overline{\textbf{0}},\overline{\textbf{1}}-\text{diag} \{ \lambda_1,...,\lambda_m \} w^Tx_i \} \rVert_2^2 $$

Let use $\gamma_{x_i}(j') := 1-(\langle w^{j'}, x_i \rangle )\chi_{\{y_i=j'\}}$,
So the derivative for a single data point is :

\begin{align*} \frac{\partial}{\partial w_k^j}\sum_{j'=1}^m max\{0, 1-(\langle w^{j'}, x_i \rangle )\chi_{\{y_i=j'\}}\} \\
&= \begin{cases} 2(1-\langle w^{j},x_i\rangle\chi_{\{y_i=j\}})(-1)x_i^{k}\chi_{\{y_i=j\}} , \gamma_{x_i}(j) >0\\
0, \gamma_{x_i}(j) \leq 0 \end{cases}\end{align*}

We now take the derivative of the hinge loss:
Let $X^T_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ row of transpose of $X$, $\sigma_i=\chi_{\{ \gamma_{x_i}(j') >0 \}}$ then

\begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k^j}\frac{C}{n}\sum_{(x_i,y_i)\in S} \sum_{j'=1}^m l(w^{j'}, (x_i,y_i))^2  \\
&= \frac{C}{n} \sum_{(x_i,y_i)\in S}2(1-\langle w^{j},x_i\rangle\chi_{\{y_i=j\}})(-1)x_i^k\chi_{\{y_i=j\}}*\sigma_i\\
&= \frac{C}{n}(-2X^T_k)^T \text{diag}(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n) (\lambda_j \overline{\mathbf{1}}-w^{jT}X)\end{align*}